# Facebook download app page for desktop app where it disappear?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, desktop-application

I have desktop application I notice that FB, change the app page ( again ),
and now the app page is some kind of fan page. ok...
So I created fan page for my desktop application. 
was reading [this](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=184605634921611) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/)

But I don't see any option to link my download page of the app , and this page I created.
What I missing here ?

Comment: What do you mean by "download page of the app"?

Comment: before the change your app page ( if its desktop app) had blue button and link to your app to download . how does things work now?

Comment: Did you create an app page from the settings?

Comment: yes i did. Advance -> App Page